# variable "using" is a not a type name?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I am currently trying to create an application in C as an assignment for school, and my professor requires me to use the following to make it compatible with his compiler:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
```

(I am using visual studio)

And for some reason `#include <string>` throws up a bunch of run time errors mainly consisting of the one in the title of the question. It pops up within a bunch of other dependencies ranging from cmath, cstudio, cstdlib, cstring, etc. So the bottom line is, can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: that's because #include <string> brings in a C++ header which won't compile with C.  You want #include <string.h> for the C language header.

Comment: `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include<string>` are good indicators you should change classes. You prof apparently does not us a C compiler, so how can he teach C programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#include <string>` is a C++ header file and therefore incompatible with C.

As others have suggested, you can change this to `#include <string.h>` so that you have a valid C header, however if your professor dictated that you use that specific set of headers, then you need to change your source file to a .ccp file instead of a .c file.

Comment: turns out this was actually the correct answer, surprisingly. I went over the course syllabus again after reading this, and he does say to use .cpp extension. Kind of strange for a course in C...

Comment: @IanLundberg: Gah.  GAH.  **GAAAHH**.  This man is not going to teach you C; he's going to teach you a subset of C++ that looks and tastes kind of like C, mostly, but is going to have some differences in semantics (casts on `malloc` ahoy).  Mixing C headers in C++ code is a guaranteed recipe for heartburn.  I'd seriously suggest looking for an alternate class; this man is going to teach you some *bad* practice.  You said you had to do this to make your code compatible with *his* compiler; do you know which compiler he's using?

Answer (score 6):

In visual studio you can  get this error if you extension is '.c' VS studio will assume the file is type c and not c++ and use the c compiler and not the c++.

In the project settings under advanced options you can select compile as C++ and then files will all be compiled as C++.  If you scroll down you will find the flag '-x' on the command line as added to it.

If you are using the gcc compiler this is the same as adding the following to the compiler command '-x c++'

Check the gcc reference for this flag.

Answer (score 1):

You're including C++ header file. Use `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

You are including a C++ library in C code. The header files without any extension are C++ header files. Having ".h" extension are C header files. C++ also accepts C header files still they have no extension. They have given same names having "c" prefix and no ".h" extension.

for example

```
<string>
```

is a C++ header

```
<string.h>
```

is a C header

```
<cstring>
```

is a C header but in a C++ code.

Comment: Oh okay, my professor must have just mistyped. Thanks!

Comment: If your professor said to uses a .cpp extension on your files, and the course is C (not C++), then you should abandon that course and find a different professor, one who knows what he is doing.